# What git commands is AzureDevops (VSO) issuing when you use the "revert" feature on a commit?

Tags: git, azure-devops

[image]

I can't find it documented anywhere on microsoft docs, but what git commands are being issued when you use this "revert" feature on a commit? ie: if I wanted to replicate this on my own without using the azure devops UI.

Edit: here's the official docs for this revert feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-view-history?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1):

This is part of Azure [Undo Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/undo?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2022), section "[Undo the changes made by a shared commit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/undo?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2022#undo-the-changes-made-by-a-shared-commit)"

> In the History tab for the current branch, right-click the commit you want to revert and choose Revert to create a new commit that undoes the changes made by the selected commit.

That is similar to the [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) command.